# what would be the best way to make the id field md5 of username, body, msg_date fields in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
structure


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blabbing` (   
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
   `msg_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
   `body` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=307 ;
```

Also if I want to add a responseto field can I use the same structure as the body field because this is a response and will have the same type of data that the field.

Comment: Do you want to MD5 your fields in a query?

Comment: I want md5 these three fields so that now message or body content has the same id, probably I could do it in the php script

Comment: SELECT md5("username"), md5("msg_date"), md5("body") FROM `blabbing`, use UPDATE if you want to make changes.

What do you mean by having the same id?

Comment: You're trying to avoid saving two copies of a message, if someone hits the "post" button twice?  Just check for a matching record once in your "Create New Message" stored procedure, and save yourself the overhead of adding an extra calculated column for one-time events.

Comment: @chumillas I am avoiding to repeat messages and confused the table, but I have realized that with id of the message would be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_tablename_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON `tablename`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.id = md5(username + body + CAST(msg_date AS CHAR));
```

Since this is likely a primary key, using a hash function on an indexed column should be avoided.  Hash functions are not sequential, so an ordered index will get fragmented *VERY* quickly.

Your best bet is to create a trigger to check the values don't already exist, or put extra code as part of the insert.  It will make for much faster inserts. Use an EXISTS with a subquery searching for a match.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you are asking, but I think you want a field to contain an MD5 of other values you are inserting, and want the database to handle it. You can try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER blabbing_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `blabbin` FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.id = md5(...);
```

As others are alluding to, if this is just to ensure uniqueness, there are probably better ways.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicates do a query and check if it returns false or true

```
SELECT body FROM blabbing WHERE username=X ORDER BY msg_date ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: can use the msid = x instead of username=X, becuase I am using the id of the user instead of its actual name to indentify each comment.